# How to collect all elements to an array from a custom Object in swift 5

Tags: arrays, swift, list

I just started learning Swift and I come from a Java background. I am looking to figure out how to collect elements of an array of objects to an array. see example below:

```
struct Employee {
    var name: String
    var age: Double
    var height: Double
    var weight: Double
}

let employees = [Employee]()
```

with the above Employee object, I have a list of employees in an array.
I would like to collect all the ages into an array similar to a lambda expression in Java.

In Java 8 you could do:

```
double[] ages = employees.stream().mapToDouble(x -> x.age).toArray()
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use [map(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/3017522-map) function like that:

```
let ages = employees.map { $0.age }
```

**Update**: As @LeoDabus said in the comments, since Swift 5.2, `map(_:)` function can be used with `KeyPath` for an even more elegant approach:

```
let ages = employees.map(\.age)
```

Comment: Or using KeyPath (Swift 5.2 or later) `employees.map(\.age)`

Comment: @LeoDabus yes, that's prettier. Thank you.